# How to set up reactive choice parameter in Jenkins multipipeline inside declarative Jenkins file

Tags: jenkins, groovy, parameters

I need a reactive choice parameter to give me 1-3 options when I choose a value for the extended choice parameter.

The following code gives me error that:

> org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:
> startup failed: WorkflowScript: 4: Build parameters cannot be defined
> as maps @ line 4, column 9.
> [$class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter',
> ^
>
> 1 error

```
pipeline {
    parameters {
        extendedChoice(defaultValue: 'none', description: 'Select the resource you want to modify', multiSelectDelimiter: ',', name: 'Resources', quoteValue: false, saveJSONParameterToFile: false, type: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT', value: 'Compute, LIVE', visibleItemCount: 2) 
        [$class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter', 
        choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
        description: 'Select a choice',
        filterLength: 1,
        filterable: true,
        name: 'choice1',
        referencedParameters: 'Resources',
        script: [$class: 'GroovyScript',
            fallbackScript: [
                classpath: [], 
                sandbox: true, 
                script: 'return ["ERROR"]'
            ],
            script: [
                classpath: [], 
                sandbox: true, 
                script: """
                    if (Resources == 'Compute') { 
                        return['aaa','bbb']
                    }
                    else {
                        return['ccc', 'ddd']
                    }
                """.stripIndent()
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

How do I achieve this in a declarative pipeline?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use below code for your requirement.

```
 properties([
    parameters([
        
        extendedChoice(defaultValue: 'none', description: 'Select the resource you want to modify', multiSelectDelimiter: ',', name: 'Resources', quoteValue: false, saveJSONParameterToFile: false, type: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT', value: 'Compute, LIVE', visibleItemCount: 2),
        [$class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter', 
        choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
        description: 'Select a choice',
        name: 'choice1',
        referencedParameters: 'Resources',
        script: [$class: 'GroovyScript',
            fallbackScript: [
                classpath: [], 
                sandbox: true, 
                script: 'return ["ERROR"]'
            ],
            script: [classpath: [], sandbox: false, script: '''
            def getChoice1(){
                def value = ""
                    switch(Resources) {
                        case "Compute":
                            value = ["aaa", "bbb"]
                            break
                        case "LIVE":
                            value = ["ccc", "ddd"]
                            break
                    }
            }
            def choice1 = getChoice1()
            return choice1
            '''
            ]
        ]
    ]
    ])
])

pipeline {
agent any
// do anything inside pipeline
}
```

Below is Jenkins UI for same.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, using your structure outside pipeline it worked! But I am getting ERROR value from choice1 no matter what I choose in Resources! Any ideas?

Comment: It worked after I changed the default value from none to Select. Does not make sense to me, but your answer was the solution. Could you please tell me why it did not work from the first time?

Comment: Above code worked for me, can you please share error logs, to help in the issue faced

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [snippet generator tool](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#snippet-generator) to generate pipeline script.
I would explain in detail before coming to main code:

See below steps:

1. Select `Properties:Set job properties`:
   [image]
2. Select `project as paramterised` along with groovy script `return ["Compute", "LIVE:selected"]`

[image]
3. Add `description` and select `choice type`
[image]
4. Add one more Active choice reactive parameter and groovy script
[image]
5.Select choice type and ensure you add the name of reference paramater that you would be using as below:
[image]
6. Click on generate pipeline script:
[image]

**Now add this in the pipeline job: Below is the code**

```
properties([parameters([[$class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter', choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT', description: 'Select the resource you want to modify', filterLength: 1, filterable: false, name: 'Resources', randomName: 'choice-parameter-843794284471400', referencedParameters: '',
script: [$class: 'GroovyScript', fallbackScript: [classpath: [], sandbox: false, script: ''],
script: [classpath: [], sandbox: false,
script: 'return ["Compute", "LIVE:selected"]']]],
[$class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter', 
 choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
 description: '', 
 filterLength: 1, filterable: false,
 name: 'choice1', 
 randomName: 'choice-parameter-843794300545400',
 referencedParameters: 'Resources',
 script: [$class: 'GroovyScript',
 fallbackScript: [classpath: [], sandbox: false, script: ''],
 script: [classpath: [], sandbox: false, 
 script: '''
 if (Resources.equals("Compute")){
                                return["aaaa","bbbb"]
                                  }
 else if(Resources.equals("LIVE")){
                                return["cccc","dddd"]
                            }''']]]])])
```

**Output**:
[image]
[image]